# WHy my URl gives disalowed characters error?

Tags: android, json, api

I am trying to build an android app for which i was going through the hackerrank api documentation. This is the general format of the request to be made :

**api.hackerrank.com/checker/submission.json -d 'source=print 1&lang=5&testcases=["1"]&api_key=yourapikeyfoobarbaz'**

I pasted my key and made the request but got the error **"The URI you submitted has disallowed characters"**

The documentation however shows that proper response has been obtained.

This is the link to the documentation : https://www.hackerrank.com/api/docs

Since i am new to android development i am not able to figure out my fault. Can someone please guide me.

Comment: "This is the general format of the request to be made" -- no, those are parameters to the **`curl`** command. Your key does not go in the URL; it goes as a parameter in a POST-ed form.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so how do i get the proper output ?

Comment: Make an HTTP POST request, per the HackerRank documentation. `source`, `lang`, `testcases`, and `api_key` are POST fields, and `http://api.hackerrank.com/checker/submission.json` is the URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try to do that !!